# Random properties pure CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm just wondering, is it possible to have randomly generated properties using only CSS, or will some javascript be required.

The effect I want to achieve is to have the coloured divs randomly positioned on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/pphheerroonn/F95Ju/2/embedded/result/

```
HTML:
<div class="box wsbg1"></div>
<div class="box wsbg2"></div>
<div class="box wsbg3"></div>
<div class="box wsbg4"></div>


CSS:
body {
    height: 600px; background-color: #66ccff;}
.box {
    height: 200px; width: 200px; 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 15px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.wsbg1 {background-color: #ec0689;}
.wsbg2 {background-color: #ffde00;}
.wsbg3 {background-color: #09aeee;}
.wsbg4 {background-color: #5eb345;}
​
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want CSS to produce random positions for those CSS elements?

Comment: Yes, I don't think its possible?

Comment: It's not possible using CSS. This is a bit of a stretch, but you could use PHP to generate random number in a certain range (or percentages, for that reason), where the value for the position would be; however, this could only apply to CSS within a `<style>` tag, and not linked stylesheets.

Answer (score 7):

No, CSS is deterministic. Either create randomness with javascript, or serve up a randomly generated css file each time with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that with CSS pre processors such as LESS or SASS, here is a relevant answer for the same:

[Possible to create random numbers in SASS / Compass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626829/possible-to-create-random-numbers-in-sass-compass)

Comment: That will only randomise the CSS at the moment it's generated. I'm also looking for a way to truly randomise CSS animations without using javascript.